# This question should not be closed

Tags: support, status-completed, closing

I saw this question (Q1) come up and get closed fairly quickly as it should have been, but it was linked to this question (Q2) which had also been closed as a duplicate to this third question (Q3)

Q1: [I can't build or destroy anything in minecraft!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87404/i-cant-build-or-destroy-anything-in-minecraft)

Q2: [Why can't I destroy or place blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82358/why-cant-i-destroy-blocks-on-minecraft)

Q3: [Why are blocks respawning in my Minecraft 1.3 SMP server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18895/why-are-blocks-respawning-in-my-minecraft-1-3-smp-server)

Question 2 might appear to be a duplicate to somebody that is not familiar with Minecraft, but they are very different questions and have very different answers. Thus Question 2 should be re-opened.

Answer (score 7):

Agreed.  Voting to reopen.  That is all.